# Sqlite Database creation, Best practise Android

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have a database with few tables. I wish to know, what is the best way to create a table in the database. My tables contain both strings(text) and numbers(int and doubles). Should I create the table with all the datatypes text, int, double etc., or should I create the table with all texts and convert them before inserting and reading for display.

Let's say this is the table that i have...

```
sqlDB.execSQL("create table if not exists "+scriptName+"(dateofpurchase text, buyorsell text," +
                " purchasedquantity int, purchasedprice double, investmentwithoutbrokerage double," +
                " brokerage double, servicetax double, stt double, stampduty double, othertaxes double," +
                " investmentwithbrokerage double)");
```

Instead of creating the table with different datatypes, if i create the table with all "text"s and do the needful conversions on the strings whenever needed.

```
sqlDB.execSQL("create table if not exists "+scriptName+"(dateofpurchase text, buyorsell text," +
                    " purchasedquantity text, purchasedprice text, investmentwithoutbrokerage text," +
                    " brokerage text, servicetax text, stt text, stampduty text, othertaxes text," +
                    " investmentwithbrokerage text)");
```

Before inserting the data into the table, i will convert all values into strings and while retrieving the values from table, (for calculations) I will convert them back to respective datatypes. For displaying on the screen, I can use them directly as strings.

If i create the table as above, what are the disadvantages/advantages over creating the table with all datatypes?

Comment: Remember SQLite doesn't really 'have' [datatypes](http://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html).

Comment: Oh Okie.. But what do you think is the more convenient way?

Comment: @wtsang02, your comment is incorrect. SQLite differentiates between text and numbers, so it certainly has type affinity.

Comment: @323go Look at what I added. no errors. [pic](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/66988308/StackOverflow/sqlite_nodatatype.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always create your tables with the proper datatypes. While in SQLite, you don't need to differentiate between, say, BYTE and INTEGER or VARCHAR(n) and TEXT, there is a marked difference between a number and a string. Using accurate types makes your model more understandable, and it will guard against invalid values, i.e. string in a numeric field. The conversions from a numeric field to a string are cheap; also consider that you may want to format currency values properly. Thus, storing them as strings is not just impractical, but may seriously complicate (and break) your code.